# Square of a contrast

Tags: mathematical-statistics, experiment-design, biostatistics, contrasts, inference

If Yi (i=1,2,....n)  are normally distributed with common variance v then consider the contrast 
             C = Sum(Ai*Yi) such that
            Sum (Ai)= 0
Now i know that C^2/Sum(Ai^2) is a v*chi sqare with one degree of freedom but I cant prove it ..is there anyone who can show me the proof

Comment: I assume that by "*v*chi sqare" you mean a chi-squared distribution scaled by $\sqrt{v}$.  The conclusion is nevertheless generally false unless the $Y_i$ are (a) independent and (b) have the same means, which might explain why you cannot prove it.

Comment: I assumed this too but still i couldn't

Comment: When you make those assumptions, $C^2/||A||^2$ is the square of a standard Normal variable, which *by definition* has a $\chi^2(1)$ distribution, *QED*.